# Uploaded Assets always get 600 File Permission and are therefore not displayed (403 Error)

Tags: assets, upload, permissions

After a fresh manual Craft CMS install everything runs fine, except uploading Assets. Well, the uploading part works fine but uploaded assets always just get file permissions of 600 (adfrw) Group and User are set correctly. Tried it with a fresh install at 2 different hosts still they always get the same permissions.
Does anyone have any idea of what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just missed the "Assets in this volume have public URLs" lightswitch while setting up the volume :)

Comment: To add to this, I've found that enabling this switch DOESN'T fix the permissions for previously uploaded files (you still get a 403 accessing these) - but those uploaded after this is set are fine.  Threw me out as changing this setting didn't seem to help until I tried uploading a new file!